# calling a javascript function from the gridview to javascript function

Tags: asp.net

I have a gridview that has a linkbutton in it, on the onclientclieck event of the link button, I want to call the javascript function and pass some of the values from the gridview to the javascript function, based on the rowindex.

Can I use the Datakeyvalues to pass the values from the gridview to javascript function. I was wondeirng if someone has any example related to this.

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can pass the values in the RowDataBound event of the grid.

```
    protected void grid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            YourData data = (YourData)e.Row.DataItem;
            LinkButton lbTest = (LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0];
            lbTest.Attributes.Add("onclick", string.Format("jsFunction({0}, {1}, {2}); return false;", data.Property1, data.Property2, data.Property3));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Its not executing the javascript function